# Migration from XAMPP in windows to MAMP in Mac

Tags: migration

Today I tried it, after many hours of frustration I quit. If someone could give me a nice step-by-step guide where I could use and work in my XAMPP hosted the project with its database, posts, pictures, categories and ID's in another computer with MAMP and work in sync with a GitHub repo.

P. S. I had all kinds of trouble with the database, site URL, browser's cache, and all mixed.

Comment: I already learned about the Duplicator plugin so now my question is different and i figure that it's better to close this one and ask another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

1. Create a folder on your Windows Desktop and give it a name (ie 
   'WebProject')
2. Find htdocs folder of XAMPP, right click on folder, Send To -> 
   Compressed Folder.
3. Move the zip file created in step 2 to the folder from Step 1.
4. Open phpMyAdmin and export your DB.  Save the file in folder from Step 1
5. Repeat the above 4 steps for each project you would like to migrate.
6. Right click on folder from Step 1, Send To -> Compressed Folder.
7. Insert a new USB thumb drive in your Windows PC.
8. Move file created in Step 6 (ie 'WebProject.zip) to USB thumb drive.
9. Take USB thumb drive and connect it to the Mac running MAMP.
10. Open Finder and drag the file from Step 8 to your Mac desktop.
11. Double-click on file from Step 10, it will decompress into a folder and disappear.
12. Open folder from Step 11 and proceed to double-click on each of the zip files contained in it.
13. Start MAMP, make sure MySQL is runnning.
14. Launch phpMyAdmin on Mac running MAMP.
15. Go to Import and browse to folder from Step 11. Import each SQL file in that folder.
16. Open MAMP and go to Hosts and click on + below Name column.  Give your first site a host name (ie mycoolsite.apple.com).
17. Click on the folder icon to the right of 'Document Root' and navigate to the folder from Step 11 and find the folder inside it containing the files you need and click on Choose.
18. Make sure both checkboxes are NOT checked and click on Create.
    19 Repeat items 16 - 18 for every site you want to develop using MAMP.

You should now configure your projects to use the localhost as their MySQL server. The user should be 'root' and whatever password you set for the root user when you first installed MAMP. The name of the DB should be the same.

To test, open a browser and point to one of the URLs you configured in Step 16 but we will connect to port 8888 (ie http://mycoolsite.apple.com:8888)

Please note that you can place the htdocs folder anywhere in your Mac.  If you put the files anywhere outside of your home directory, make sure your user is owner of the folder and all its contents and all files and folders have 755 permissions. Type 'man chown' and 'man chmod' in a Mac Terminal window for more information.